# io.helidon.webserver.ServerResponse.send() throwing error on server but file downloaded on front end

Tags: helidon, helidon-httpclient, helidon-webclient

Trying to write one sample for (file upload and download) error in server.
Though it downloads the file in the frontend, getting error in server.

For Routing--

```
WebServer.builder(getRouting()).port(8080).build().start();
    
private static Routing getRouting() throws Exception{
        
        return Routing.builder().register("/filetest", JerseySupport.builder().register(FileController.class).build())
            .build();
    }


@RequestScoped
public class FileController {
     @Context
     ServerRequest req;
     @Context
     ServerResponse res;
    @GET
    @Path("/{fname}")
    public void download(@PathParam("fname") String fname) {
        
        try {
            //Getting the file 
            java.nio.file.Path filepath = Paths.get("c:/"+fname+".txt");
            ResponseHeaders headers = res.headers();
            headers.contentType(io.helidon.common.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            headers.put(Http.Header.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, ContentDisposition.builder()
                    .filename(filepath.getFileName().toString())
                    .build()
                    .toString());
           
           res.send(filepath);         
        }catch(Exception e) {
            
        }
}
```

> Jul 29, 2021 6:20:36 PM
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest defaultHandler
> WARNING: Default error handler: Unhandled exception encountered.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Unhandled 'cause' of this
> exception encountered.    at
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest.defaultHandler(RequestRouting.java:397)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest.nextNoCheck(RequestRouting.java:377)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest.next(RequestRouting.java:420)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.jersey.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:133)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:438)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.jersey.JerseySupport$JerseyHandler.lambda$doAccept$3(JerseySupport.java:299)
> at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:117)
> at
> io.helidon.common.context.ContextAwareExecutorImpl.lambda$wrap$5(ContextAwareExecutorImpl.java:154)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> io.helidon.common.http.AlreadyCompletedException: Response status code
> and headers are already completed (sent to the client)!   at
> io.helidon.webserver.HashResponseHeaders$CompletionSupport.runIfNotCompleted(HashResponseHeaders.java:384)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.HashResponseHeaders.httpStatus(HashResponseHeaders.java:251)
> at io.helidon.webserver.Response.status(Response.java:122)  at
> io.helidon.webserver.Response.status(Response.java:48)    at
> io.helidon.webserver.jersey.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:81)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:607)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:373)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:363)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:258)
> ... 14 more
>
> Jul 29, 2021 6:20:36 PM
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest defaultHandler
> WARNING: Cannot perform error handling of the throwable (see cause of
> this exception) because headers were already sent
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Headers already sent. Cannot handle
> the cause of this exception.  at
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest.defaultHandler(RequestRouting.java:405)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest.nextNoCheck(RequestRouting.java:377)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.RequestRouting$RoutedRequest.next(RequestRouting.java:420)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.jersey.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:133)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:438)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:263)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.jersey.JerseySupport$JerseyHandler.lambda$doAccept$3(JerseySupport.java:299)
> at io.helidon.common.context.Contexts.runInContext(Contexts.java:117)
> at
> io.helidon.common.context.ContextAwareExecutorImpl.lambda$wrap$5(ContextAwareExecutorImpl.java:154)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
> io.helidon.common.http.AlreadyCompletedException: Response status code
> and headers are already completed (sent to the client)!   at
> io.helidon.webserver.HashResponseHeaders$CompletionSupport.runIfNotCompleted(HashResponseHeaders.java:384)
> at
> io.helidon.webserver.HashResponseHeaders.httpStatus(HashResponseHeaders.java:251)
> at io.helidon.webserver.Response.status(Response.java:122)  at
> io.helidon.webserver.Response.status(Response.java:48)    at
> io.helidon.webserver.jersey.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:81)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:607)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:373)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:363)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:258)
> ... 14 more

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are mixing Helidon SE and Helidon MP?

Answer (score 2):

When using Helidon MP, Jersey is responsible for sending the response.

In the code above you are using the underlying WebServer and sending a response inside the body of a JAXRS resource method, when Jersey sends the response the exception is thrown because it was already sent.

[Helidon MP Multipart example](https://github.com/oracle/helidon/blob/2.3.2/examples/microprofile/multipart/src/main/java/io/helidon/examples/microprofile/multipart/FileService.java#L69)

[Jersey Multipart documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest3x/media.html#d0e9087)